# Вставить в html через js код, который является скриптом

Tags: javascript, html

Есть много страниц html, нужно в каждую вставить определенный код. Решил делать это через js. Но если через js у меня получается вставить div, то вставить скрипт не выходит (скрипт не работает).
файл test.js и index.html:

```js
const headerText = `
<script>
    for(let i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        alert("Из шляпы достали "+i+" кролика!")
    }
</script>
`;

function setHeader() {
    const header = document.createElement("script");
    header.textContent = headerText;
    document.body.prepend(header);
}
setHeader();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <script src="test.js" type=""></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Удали из headerText =  тэги <script> оставь только код

Answer (score 0):

```js
const code = "alert('hello world')";

let scp = document.createElement("script"); // Создаём тэг скрипт
let data = document.createTextNode(code); // Создаём текст из data
scp.appendChild(data); // Ложем текст в скрипт
document.body.appendChild(scp); // Помещаем скрипт в элемент в данном случае в <BODY>
```